# Я хочу получить список определенных объектов из массива json который я получаю с помощью Retrofit2 в чем у меня ошибка?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

Структура Json:
[image: Структура]
P.S Ссылка не динамическая поэтому есть просто массив данных Json;

MainActivity.class:

```
private Retrofit retrofit;
Response response;
List<Pandomats> pandomats;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);





    Service.getInstance()
            .getJSONApi()
            .loadList()
            .enqueue(new Callback<List<Pandomats>>() {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Pandomats>> call, Response<List<Pandomats>> response) {
                    pandomats.addAll(response.body());



                    Log.v("ListPandomats", String.valueOf(pandomats.size()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Pandomats>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

Service.java :

```
public class Service {
private static final Service ourInstance = new Service();
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://myurl";
private Retrofit mRetrofit;

public static Service getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}

private Service() {
    mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

}

public JsonPlaceApi getJSONApi() {
    return mRetrofit.create(JsonPlaceApi.class);
}

}
```

JsonPlaceApi.java :

```
public interface JsonPlaceApi {
@GET("/api/device/get/")
Call<List<Pandomats>> loadList();
}
```

Pandomats.java :

```
public class Pandomats {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String address;
@SerializedName("model")
@Expose
private String model;
@SerializedName("latitude")
@Expose
private Double latitude;
@SerializedName("longitude")
@Expose
private Double longitude;
@SerializedName("lastDeviceData")
@Expose
private LastDeviceData lastDeviceData;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private Object image;



public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public Double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}


public LastDeviceData getLastDeviceData() {
    return lastDeviceData;
}

public void setLastDeviceData(LastDeviceData lastDeviceData) {
    this.lastDeviceData = lastDeviceData;
}
public Object getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Object image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
У меня есть массив Json в нем 96 разных моделей, мне надо Получить список со всеми 96 моделями из этого массива

Comment: Не совсем понятен мне вопрос, во вьюхолдере засовывайте то что вам нужно в список. В активити получаете данные, в он респонс устанавливаете адаптеру список. В адаптере сеттите то что нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `holder` попробуйте это:

```
holder.text_view.setText(pandomats.get(position).getModel());
```

А в `onResponse` это:

```
adapter = new Adapter(pandomats);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Видимо я плохо изложил суть вопрос мне надо проинициализировать список  getModel'ом который лежит в Pandomats.class, но я не знаю к чему его применять. Если я пишу pandomats.getModel, то пишет что такого метода нет

Comment: у меня есть массив Json в котором 96 блоков с информацией, но мне надо выполнить getModel и создать список с моделями всех 96 блоков

Comment: Вы можете вытянуть абсолютно любой элемент из любого блока. Что в вашем понимании getModel , я вижу она возвращает просто String.  К примеру так: setText(pandomats.get(position).getLastDeviceData.getId();

Comment: У меня есть массив Json в нем 96 разных моделей , мне надо Получить список со всеми 96 моделями из этого массива

Comment: Извините, я тупил